# Xpath selects just some tr

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

I have an html code like this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th><a href="example.html" title="exemple_title_th"></a><th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>       
<tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="example2.html" title="exemple_title_td"></a><td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>       
<tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="example3.html" title="exemple_title_td"></a><td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>       
<tr>
<tr>
    <th><a href="example4.html" title="exemple_title_th"></a><th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>       
<tr>
```

And I want just the **tr** that don't have a th tag.
I tried this xpath:

```
//a[@title="exemple_title_th"]/following::tr
```

but it returns all **tr** after the first-one, including the following tr that contain the th tag that I don't want. What's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xpath, `//a[@title="exemple_title_th"]/following::tr`, uses following axis, which is supposed to select all the following `tr` elements in the document order.

To select `tr` elements in the whole document that do not have a `th`child, you can use a simple xpath like:

```
//tr[not(th)]
```